# Finding $\beta$ as a function of $\alpha$ and $\mu$ in hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

**Question:** Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4 \stackrel{iid}\sim \mathrm N(\mu,1), \mu$ unknown. We want to decide between $H_0:\mu = 2 $ and $ H_1: \mu \ne 2$. If we require significance level $\alpha$, find $\beta$ as a function of $\mu$ and $\alpha$.

**Solution:** $W = \cfrac{\overline X - 2}{\frac12} = 2\overline X-4. \because \overline X \sim \mathrm N(\mu,\frac14), W \sim \mathrm N(2\mu -4, 1) \\ \beta = P(|W| \le z_{\frac{\alpha}2} \mid \mu \ne 2) \\ = P(-z_{\frac\alpha 2} - (2\mu-4) \le W - (2\mu-4) \le z_\frac\alpha 2 -(2\mu-4) \mid \mu \ne 2) \\ \color{red}{=} \Phi(z_\frac\alpha2 - 2\mu+4)-\Phi(-z_\frac\alpha2-2\mu+4)$

My only discomfort with this solution is the equals sign that I highlighted red. I would be totally fine with this step if my probabilities were not conditioned on the event $\mu\ne2$. Why can I take this step? Thanks for the help.

Comment: $\mu\ne 2$ is not an event, the probability is a function of $\mu$. Saying $\mu\ne 2$ does not affect the general probability as a function of $\mu$.

Comment: Why do you say $\mu \ne 2$ is not an event? @StubbornAtom

Comment: There is nothing random about $\mu$; it is a constant. You are just finding a probability when $\mu\ne 2$ (i.e. for any $\mu$). This is not really a conditional probability.

Comment: When you say (i.e. for any $\mu$) isn't it for any $\mu$ except $2$? Then doesn't this change the formula in some way? @StubbornAtom

Comment: Yes, it holds for any $\mu$ except $2$. But formula does not change.